# HTML Master Page - Trying to remove blank space

Tags: html, asp.net

I've been designing this website for my ASP.NET class, and I'm having some issues with a blank space...I've checked everywhere for any breaks, margins or padding that might be causing it and I can't for the life of me figure it out. The blank space is showing up somewhere on the master page, as I've got a completely blank webform referencing it (though the ones that have content do the same thing). The blank space shows up at the very top, above the jumbotron. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MANHammerStudios.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %>MANHammer Studios</title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */
    .navbar {          
        border-radius: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    ul.nav.navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }

    /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */
    .jumbotron {
        background-image: url('Assets/1.jpg');
        height: 300px;           
        background-position:center;            
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    h2{
        color:firebrick;
    }
    h3{
        text-align:center;
    }
    h1 {
        text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
    }
    body {
        background: transparent;
    }

    html {
        background-image: url('Assets/bgMC.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
        padding: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container2 text-center">
        <h1>MANHammer Studios</h1>
        <p style="text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;">Miniature Painting Service</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use this: body{margin:0;}

Comment: Attempted this; no change.

Comment: How many pixels is the blank space?

Comment: Roughly 70 pixels

Comment: Woo..  this is a serious problem. I was thinking it is about 6-7  px. Can i see the web page? Is this online?

Comment: I just uploaded the zip file to my google drive at the link below. Not sure how well it will work since I've never tried doing it with a full project, but worth a try. I appreciate the help, I plan on modifying this over time and using it quite extensively, so I very much want to fix these kind of things as early as possible.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02SpvuUkSB9RFBiWnk4b0pPZFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you remove the tag <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" /> and test again? That does not works in my sample.

Comment: Here i do not see any blank space?!

Comment: The <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" /> line is necessary for the CSS; without that the navbar and all the content just turns into plain, unformatted text.

Comment: Are you sure the link is true? as i said there is no blank space (at the top of page is black menu, and there is not div class="jumbotron".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Site.css`, you have:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

And in your `.jumbotron` class in `Site.master` you have:

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

There's your 70px!

Remove those lines and the 70px on top of your page will be gone.

Comment: He says the blank space is 70px.

Comment: Adjusting the margin & padding for all elements didn't change it, sadly.

Comment: @krlzlx, Is this technically possible that i see some thing else that you see? (I mean the site linked.)

Comment: Nevermind, we're good! Was having a problem refreshing. Thank you so much!